# web sphere - Web Application not found error 

Tags: error-handling, websphere

I'm trying deploying my application in WAS 5 & 6, there is an error message 
"VirtualHost or Web application not found"
"The web group default_host / RbsWeb has not been defined" as below image

when the application is down, there any way so that i can change/redirect to another .jsp page for this error, how this can be done, do need to do anything in default host under Server - Environment - Virtual Host

thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: I'm not going to copy this thread, but it seems to be saying there is one case which you can't do anything about. In case someone doesn't come up with a better answer for you. http://fixunix.com/websphere/373084-use-custom-404-page-when-running-but-application-isstopped.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating an application that has a WAR with a context-root of "/".  That WAR should become the "default" when no other WAR is installed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a web app with a context-root of "/" will take over all the time. We've inadvertently done that before. (And/or it may cause other apps to even fail to deploy due to a conflict.)

Comment: Hmmm... maybe where I saw it was when the FileServing servlet was enabled, thus making the application own /*. At least in some versions of WebSphere, having that enabled has been the default as well. Just in case anybody finds this solution again. I think Michael Lucas' answer might be the better one now available.

Answer (score 1):

In WAS 6 and above you can use the following custom property (set on the server's Web Container in the admin console) to return a custom message:
`com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webgroupvhostnotfound`

I have found that this property can even contain html code! (this was tested on WAS 8.0.0.5)

Note that for WAS 6.0, 6.1 and 7.0 this feature is available as a fixpack. See [PK85685](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK85685).

**Instructions:**

1. In the administrative console click Servers > Server Types > WebSphere application servers > server_name > Web Container Settings > Web container .
2. Under Additional Properties select Custom Properties.
3. On the Custom Properties page, click New.
4. On the settings page, enter the name of the custom property that you want to configure in the Name field (`com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webgroupvhostnotfound` in this case) and the value that you want to set it to in the Value field. (as I mentioned, the value can contain html)
5. Click Apply or OK.
6. Click Save on the console task bar to save your configuration changes.
7. Restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

Standard practice is to front the app server with a web server.

This page (*VirtualHost or Web Application not found when you application is stopped*) should come back as a **404** error back to the web server.

Use a web server redirect directive to a custom page that you want to display to your customers.

HTH
Manglu

Comment: But as long as the WAS plugin is enabled and owning that context root, it won't give the 404 back to the web server to handle.